# Математический маятник, анимация демонстрирующая этот эффект

Tags: css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

*Математический маятник — осциллятор, представляющий собой механическую систему, состоящую из материальной точки на конце невесомой нерастяжимой нити или лёгкого стержня и находящуюся в однородном поле сил тяготения. Другой конец нити (стержня) обычно неподвижен.* (подробнее см. Wikipedia <sup>[ref](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)</sup>)

[image: Математический маятник]

Меня заинтересовал [вопрос (Колыбель Ньютона, анимация демонстрирующая этот эффект)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1265300/377637) участника [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt), где необходимо было создать анимацию, демонстрирующую данный физический опыт, в связи с чем у меня возник встречный вопрос.

Вот код математического маятника в положении равновесия на `CSS`:

```css
/*Маятник*/

.newton_cradle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black, transparent 100px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, lightgray 3%, gray 60%, lightgray 100%);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}


/*Украшательства маятника*/

.newton_cradle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(10px);
}


/*Нить*/

.newton_cradle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 48px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 2px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="newton_cradle"></div>
```

Вот код математического маятника в положении равновесия на `SMIL SVG`:

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-100 45 220 45" height="280px" width="500px">

<g>
  <!--Маятник-->
  <circle r="20" cy="67" cx="31.75" fill="url(#gr)" stroke="none" stroke-width="4.99999" />
  <!--Нить-->
  <path transform="scale(0.26458333)" d="M 120 40 L 120 180 L 120 40 z" fill="none" stroke="dimgray" stroke-width="2px" />
</g>

<!--Украшательства маятника-->
<radialGradient id="gr" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%"><stop stop-color="white" offset="10%"></stop><stop stop-color="darkgray" offset="45%"></stop><stop stop-color="gray" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0"/></radialGradient>

</svg>
```

**Вопрос:**
Как воспроизвести анимацию маятника, совершающего колебания по дуге окружности радиуса, как показано на рисунке выше? Угол отклонения от вертикали большого значения не имеет. Важнее всего в реализации понять — как при такой анимации оставить один конец (центр вращения) нерастяжимой нити (стержня) неподвижным. Интересует подробное описание такой реализации создания эффекта анимации и трансформации средствами и технологиями `CSS` и `SMIL SVG`.

Comment: Не согласен что этот вопрос схож с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265300). Хоть и схожие реализации, одно от другого отличается "механикой".

Comment: для сайта механиков отличия, действительно, весьма существенны. для данного же сайта, сайта программистов, как раз важна программная реализация. а она схожа до степени «разбиваем один цикл для большого диапазона на два цикла с меньшими диапазонами» (этот вопрос — «один цикл», вопрос-дубликат — «два цикла»).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статика, без анимации

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">  
<defs>
   <radialGradient id="Rg" r="90%" fx="50%" fy="30%">
        <stop stop-color="#F3F3F3" offset="5%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#3E3D44" offset="45%"></stop>    
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.72"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
           <!-- Траектория движения шарика -->
<circle fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" cx="200" cy="10" r="200" />
                 <!-- Верхняя полка -->
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="20" points="0,0 400,0"/>    
                 <!-- Левая граница -->
 <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 58.58,151.42" />     
                 <!-- Правая граница -->
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 341.42, 151.42"/>

            <!-- Шарик на нитке -->
   <g id="G1" fill="url(#Rg)" > 
           <!-- Нитка -->
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#4C4B53" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
        <circle  fill="url(#Rg)" stroke-width="3"  cx="200" cy="210" r="20" />
   </g>
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />  
</svg>
```

Для анимации колебания маятника лучше всего использовать `transform="rotate"` [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)

> **rotate(`<a>` `[<x> <y>]`)** Поворот на `a` градусов вокруг указанной точки. Если необязательные параметры `x` и `y` опущены, поворот будет
> осуществляться вокруг начала координат текущей пользовательской
> системы

Поэтому необходимо найти и указать точные координаты центра вращения.

В этом примере их находить не надо, так как при проектировании они были выбраны заранее. Это желтый круг с координатами  `x="200"`и `y="10"`

```
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />
```

Из центра вращения начнется линия подвески шарика

```
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#4C4B53" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
```

Чтобы нитка и шарик анимировались синхронно, нужно объединить их в группу и команду анимации применить уже к группе:

```
 <animateTransform xlink:href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="0.5s"
       dur="4s"
       values="
         45, 200, 10;
        -45, 200,10;
         45, 200, 10"
     repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
```

В атрибуте `values` указаны максимальные углы отклонения шарика

Для реализации анимации уже всё готово:

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<defs>
   <radialGradient id="Rg" r="90%" fx="50%" fy="30%">
        <stop stop-color="#F3F3F3" offset="5%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#3E3D44" offset="45%"></stop>    
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.72"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
           <!-- Траектория движения шарика -->
<circle fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" cx="200" cy="10" r="200" />
                 <!-- Верхняя полка -->
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="20" points="0,0 400,0"/>    
 
 <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 58.58,151.42">
    </polyline>   
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 341.42, 151.42"/>

            <!-- Шарик на нитке -->
<g id="G1" fill="url(#Rg)" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(45, 200, 10)" >
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
<circle  fill="url(#Rg)" stroke-width="3"  cx="200" cy="210" r="20" />
 </g>
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="0.5s"
       dur="2.5s"
       values="
         45, 200, 10;
        -45, 200,10;
         45, 200, 10"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />  
</svg>
```

Как комментирует **@MBo**

> Угловую скорость менять возможно? У реального маятника в нижней точке
> скорость выше, в верхних до нуля уменьшается. При равной скорости
> смотрится так, будто от стенок отлетает

Для решения можно воспользоваться добавлением к анимации атрибута
`keySplines =" 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97; 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97"`

Подобрать параметры можно с помощью [генератора](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1599)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из графика видно что начальный и конечный участок анимации будут идти медленно, а середина будет намного быстрее

**Финальный код:**

Добавлено к предыдущему примеру анимации:

```
calcMode="spline"
 keySplines =" 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97; 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97"
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<defs>
   <radialGradient id="Rg" r="90%" fx="50%" fy="30%">
        <stop stop-color="#F3F3F3" offset="5%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#3E3D44" offset="45%"></stop>    
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.72"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
           <!-- Траектория движения шарика -->
<circle fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" cx="200" cy="10" r="200" />
                 <!-- Верхняя полка -->
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="20" points="0,0 400,0"/>    
 
 <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 58.58,151.42">
    </polyline>   
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 341.42, 151.42"/>

            <!-- Шарик на нитке -->
<g id="G1" fill="url(#Rg)" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(45, 200, 10)"  >
    <polyline   fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
      <circle  fill="url(#Rg)" stroke-width="3"  cx="200" cy="210" r="20" />
</g>
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="0.5s"
       dur="2.5s"
       values="
         45, 200, 10;
        -45, 200,10;
         45, 200, 10"
         calcMode="spline"
         keySplines =" 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97; 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
            /> 
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />  
</svg>
```

Универсальность этого решения показывает, что достаточно изменить только углы отклонения маятника и всё будет также работать
Угол отклонения 60 градусов:

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400"  >  
<defs>
   <radialGradient id="Rg" r="90%" fx="50%" fy="30%">
        <stop stop-color="#F3F3F3" offset="5%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#3E3D44" offset="45%"></stop>    
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.72"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
           <!-- Траектория движения шарика -->
<circle fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" cx="200" cy="10" r="200" />
                 <!-- Верхняя полка -->
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="20" points="0,0 400,0"/>    
 
 <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 58.58,151.42">
    </polyline>   
   <polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="15,7.5" points="200,10 341.42, 151.42"/>

            <!-- Шарик на нитке -->
<g id="G1" fill="url(#Rg)" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(60, 200, 10)" >
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
      <circle  fill="url(#Rg)" stroke-width="3"  cx="200" cy="210" r="20" />
</g>
   <animateTransform xlink:href="#G1"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       begin="0.5s"
       dur="2.5s"
       values="
       60, 200, 10;
        -60, 200,10;
         60, 200, 10"
         calcMode="spline"
         keySplines =" 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97; 0.63 0.015 0.13 0.97"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />  
</svg>
```

### CSS вариант

Не вижу смысла делать в CSS то, с чем хорошо справляется и для чего предназначена SVG
Графику: потолок, центр вращения, траектория движения, границы отклонения маятника оставил в SVG

Все стили SVG, которые возможно, перенес в `<style>`

Анимация качания маятника реализовал с помощью `animation` `@keyframes`

```css
.poly {
fill:none;
stroke:#d3d3d3;
stroke-width:3;
stroke-dasharray:15,7.5;
} 
.G1 {
transform:translate(0,0) rotate(45deg); 
transform-origin:200px 10px;
animation: pan 4s ease infinite 0.5s;
}

@keyframes pan {
0%{transform:rotate(45deg);}
50%{transform:rotate(-45deg);}
100%{transform:rotate(45deg);}

}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<defs>
   <radialGradient id="Rg" r="90%" fx="50%" fy="30%">
        <stop stop-color="#F3F3F3" offset="5%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#3E3D44" offset="45%"></stop>    
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.72"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs> 
           <!-- Траектория движения шарика -->
<circle class="poly" id="circ1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="200" />
                 <!-- Верхняя полка -->
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="20" points="0,0 400,0"/>    
 
 <polyline class="poly" fill="none"  points="200,10 58.58,151.42">
    </polyline>   
   <polyline class="poly" points="200,10 341.42, 151.42"/>

            <!-- Шарик на нитке -->
<g class="G1" fill="url(#Rg)"  >
    <polyline   fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  points="200,10 200,210"/>
      <circle  fill="url(#Rg)" stroke-width="3"  cx="200" cy="210" r="20" />
</g>
  
                          <!-- Центр вращения -->
 <circle fill="gold" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  cx="200" cy="10" r="4" />  
</svg>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' Благодарю, отдельным ответом увы, не получится, вопрос закрыт, переоткрыть тоже не могу, так как уже открывал ((((

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант такой анимации с помощью технологии `CSS`.

Анимацию маятника, совершающего колебания, можно воспроизвести с помощью правила `@keyframes` и установить для этого правила общие ключевые кадры, включая в них нужные свойства и значения. Такая анимация является совсем не сложной, поэтому достаточно использование ключевых слов `from` и `to`.

Угол отклонения от вертикали мы можем воспроизвести с помощью свойства `transform` и функции трансформации `rotate`. [*Подробнее об этом свойстве*](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform)

Функция `rotate` позволяет нам повернуть элемент на заданный угол. Синтаксис следующий: `transform: rotate(угол)`; Угол наклона мы можем задать, например, `30deg` как положительное значение (по часовой стрелке) и `-30deg` как отрицательное (против часовой стрелки). [*Подробнее об этом значении*](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/angle)

```css
/*Анимация*/

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}


/*Маятник*/

.newton_cradle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black, transparent 100px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, lightgray 3%, gray 60%, lightgray 100%);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  animation: animate 0.8s infinite alternate linear;
}


/*Украшательства маятника*/

.newton_cradle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(10px);
}


/*Нить*/

.newton_cradle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 48px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 2px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="newton_cradle"></div>
```

Теперь у нас остается самый важный вопрос: **как при такой анимации оставить один конец (точку поворота) нерастяжимой нити (стержня) неподвижным**?

Вернемся к функции `rotate`. Вот ее определение: *она позволяет нам повернуть элемент на заданный угол относительно точки трансформации, задаваемой свойством `transform-origin`*.

Свойство `transform-origin` устанавливает координаты точки, относительно которой будет происходить трансформация элемента. Синтаксис следующий: `transform-origin: x y z;`, где `x`,`y`,`z` — это координаты по оси X, Y и Z соответственно.  [*Подробнее об этом свойстве*](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform-origin)

Итак, применим это свойство на практике, установим для него нужные нам значения: `transform-origin: 50% -90px 0;`, и посмотрим, что у нас получилось в результате:

```css
/*Анимация*/

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
}


/*Маятник*/

.newton_cradle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black, transparent 100px);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, lightgray 3%, gray 60%, lightgray 100%);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  animation: animate 0.8s infinite alternate linear;
  
  transform-origin: 50% -90px 0;
}


/*Украшательства маятника*/

.newton_cradle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  filter: blur(10px);
}


/*Нить*/

.newton_cradle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90px;
  left: 48px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 2px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="newton_cradle"></div>
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос, полезный. Но я думаю быстро на него ответят. Я завтра посмотрю, сегодня уже устал.. (((( PS  На мой взгляд нить надо длиннее делать, тогда при плохом расчете координат дефекты  будут виднее

Comment: Угловую скорость менять возможно? У реального маятника в нижней точке скорость выше, в верхних до нуля уменьшается. При равной скорости смотрится так, будто от стенок отлетает.

Comment: У реального механического маятника характер движения - синусоида, характер изменения скорости - тоже синусоида, только с опережением на 90 градусов угла отклонения. Для реалистичности необходимо симитировать все процессы, происходящие в механическом маятнике, а CSS для этого не подойдёт, нужен JavaScript. Алгоритм в том, чтобы разбить всё движение на шаги и с каждым шагом скорость должна уменьшаться на величину, прямопропорциональную разности между конечным и начальным углом отклонения в текущем шаге. Плюс ещё нужно учесть трение, и с результирующей скорости вычесть коефициент трения.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант анимации маятника с помощью технологии `SMIL SVG`, и воспроизвести совершающие колебания с помощью трансформации `type="translate"` — перемещений шарика по осям `x` и `y` ([подробнее о типах преобразований](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)), а также отдельно перерисовки элемента нити, подбирая подходящие значения для атрибута `d`, который предоставляет определение пути для рисования [подробнее об атрибуте](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d). Посмотрим, что у нас из этого получится:

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="-110 45 220 45" height="280px" width="500px">

  <!--Анимация маятника-->
  <animateTransform xlink:href="#an1" attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" values="0,0; 36.25,-5; 0,0; -36.25,-5; 0,0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
      
  <!--Анимация нити-->
  <animate xlink:href="#an2" attributeName="d" begin="0s" values="M 120 40 L 120 180 L 120 40 z; M 120 40 L 220 170 L 120 40 z; M 120 40 L 120 180 L 120 40 z; M 120 40 L 20 170 L 120 40 z; M 120 40 L 120 180 L 120 40 z" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />

<g>
  <!--Маятник-->
  <circle id="an1" r="20" cy="67" cx="31.75" fill="url(#gr)" stroke="none" stroke-width="4.99999" />
  <!--Нить-->
  <path id="an2" transform="scale(0.26458333)" d="M 120 40 L 120 180 L 120 40 z" fill="none" stroke="dimgray" stroke-width="2px" />
</g>

<!--Украшательства маятника-->
<radialGradient id="gr" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%"><stop stop-color="white" offset="10%"></stop><stop stop-color="darkgray" offset="45%"></stop><stop stop-color="gray" offset="100%" stop-opacity="0"/></radialGradient>

</svg>
```

**Вывод:** Не сложно заметить, что такой способ воспроизведения анимации маятника смотрится не совсем реалистично. Если конечно слишком сильно постараться, то вполне возможно добиться большей реалистичности, однако это будет более трудоемкий процесс. Кроме этого, такой вариант усложняется еще тем, что возникает необходимость использовать две анимации, когда можно обойтись только одной. Очевидно, что для воспроизведения анимации маятника более верным способом будет использование трансформации именно вращения элемента `type="rotate"`.